# Can you export data provided by a chatbot-user into tailored JSONs from Dialogflow?

Tags: json, dialogflow-es

When having users answering questions to a chatbot, would there be any way to export the data a given user has provided into a tailored JSON-format that we can then use in our systems and databases? If not, which format and structure would it be possible to export the data into?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? "Export" to where? What do you see the data flow looking like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to bounce it off of your webhook server. You cannot customize the outbound diagflow JSON.

Your outbound Google Diagflow JSON would be received by your own server webhook.  Process the inbound JSON request, and then simply send it onward to your outbound server, or directly via a server db client connection to your database.